# How to search a particular object or field in org

Tags: object

I need to search a particular object or field in org.It takes lot of time randomly searching and guessing.

Please suggest something.

Comment: Searching means you want to see the metadata or data?

Comment: Have you tried SOQL or SOSL? [SOQL and SOSL Queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of free apps on the App Exchange that are capable of doing the types of things you're describing. Just to mention a few: [Field Dependency Finder](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5ekWEAR), [Metadata Search](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wgF7EAI), [Cloudingo Studio](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009xMDNEA2), [Octopus](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5cEKEAZ), [Schema Surfer](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wZM3EAM) and [SmartSearch](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4tPgEAJ). Of the ones I've listed, Metadata Search has worked well for me when doing the sort of thing I think you're attempting to describe.